# jQuery UI AutoComplete Crashing With Ajax & Json

Tags: ajax, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Don't know if it matters, but the msg.d is about 300 rows long.  I get properly formatted Json data when I alert msg.d.

```
$("#supplierSelect").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SupplierAdmin.aspx/PopulateSupplierSelectDropDownList",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                response( $.map( msg.d, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: item.title,
                        value: item.turninId
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    }
}).fadeIn();
```

Lots of thanks if you can tell me how to only fadeIn when success.

**Edit:**  The "properly formatted Json data" actually has quotes around the label and value, and the ordering is switched.  Checking now to see if it makes a difference.  Sorry for incomplete info.

**Edit2:**  I went with response( $($.parseJSON(msg.d)).map( function()... instead, and now when I type anything, the autocomplete drops down the whole list of names and selecting one puts the value in the box.  Am I right to assume this isn't correct functionality?

Comment: It probably *is* the fact that the response is 300 rows long. Does it not crash if the result set is smaller?

Comment: Also, you really need to set the ajax data parameter... something like `data: request.term` at least.  The response callback needs to get the already filtered items.

Comment: For edit2 that is the correct functionality. If you want to show less items you need to filter it on the server by sending request.term over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to add parseJSON to the map.